# Azure VPN Client Windows Server 2016R2

Tags: azure, windows-server, windows-store

Is there any way to get the Azure VPN client to work on Windows Server 2016R2?

At the time of this post, the latest version was 2.2159.179.0 (Jan 12, 2023) and it said the minimum OS requirement was Windows 10 version 17763.0 or higher, Windows Server 2022 
https://install.appcenter.ms/users/user-microsoft/apps/azure-vpn-client-1/distribution_groups/publicgroup/releases/11

I tried sideloading; enabling developer mode; double clicking the .msixbundle file and even running the PowerShell files manually, but usually I either get a silent failure, or I get an error like this: 
**"Error: The package or bundle is not digitally signed or its signature is corrupted."**

NOTE: There is a way to get this app from the Windows Store, but I have not been able to do that on my Windows Server 2016R2 machine.